# console.log only [[ promise Result ]] reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, console.log

My console show this

[image]

How can I only console.log the [[ PromiseResult ]], **only the text value!**

here is my code

```
    fetch('/upload', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data

    }).then(response => {
        console.log(response.json())
    })
```

Comment: console.log(response.data)

Comment: "cuidado y protección del planeta""desarrollo humano intégräl""respeto a la dígnidad de las personas, health care